# Saber o nth do ítem clicado para selecionar um input no mesmo nth?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma tabela onde possuo um checkbox para habilitar a edição de vários ítens ao mesmo tempo, ou seja posso editar vários desde que o input esteja selecionado, mas tenho um problema que se desejar editar apenas um não ter a necessidade de selecionar o checkbox.

```js
function selecionaCompromissos() {
  var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('agrupaPagto');
  
    gravaArray(ids);
  }

function gravaArray(dados) {
  var array_dados = dados;

  var teste = Array();
  var contador = 0;

  for (var x = 0; x <= array_dados.length; x++) {
    if (typeof array_dados[x] == 'object') {
      if (array_dados[x].checked) {
        teste[x] = array_dados[x].id;
        contador++;
      }
    }
  }
  teste = teste.filter(Boolean);  
  console.log(teste);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Número</th>
      <th>Vencimento</th>
      <th>Parcela</th>
      <th>Valor</th>
      <th>Boleto</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="agrupaPagto" id="10" value="125" name="txtAgrupa" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Art Pneus</td>
      <td><a class="tool_tip" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="2">343</a></td>
      <td>10/10/2017</td>
      <td>2 <b>de</b> 2<span style="color: red"> </span></td>
      <td>R$ 125,00</td>

      <td style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">Em aberto&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_compromissos" onclick="selecionaCompromissos()">Pagar</a></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="agrupaPagto" id="11" value="221.00" name="txtAgrupa" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Maria Bonita</td>
      <td><a class="tool_tip" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="teste">532</a></td>
      <td>18/10/2017</td>
      <td>1 <b>de</b> 4<span style="color: red"> </span></td>
      <td>R$ 221,00</td>

      <td style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">Em aberto&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_compromissos" onclick="selecionaCompromissos()">Pagar</a></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A aplicação funciona mas tem que estar selecionado, mas a questão fica se o usuário for editar apenas uma linha e selecionar sem a necessidade de marcar o `checkbox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar o `checkbox` da linha clicada com:

```
elemento.closest('tr').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

Analisando seu código, uma sugestão é passar o link clicado enviando um `this` como parâmetro na função `selecionaCompromissos()`, assim:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_compromissos" onclick="selecionaCompromissos(this)">Pagar</a>
```

Desta forma, o "elemento" citado lá acima seria esse `this` recebido na função como `i`:

```
function selecionaCompromissos(i) {...
```

Depois você pode repassar essa informação para a outra função `gravaArray()` pegando a `id` do respectivo `checkbox` e criar a array apenas com 1 `id`. Ficaria assim:

```js
function selecionaCompromissos(i) {

   var idc = i.closest('tr').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

   var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('agrupaPagto');

   gravaArray(ids,idc);
}

function gravaArray(dados,idc) {
   var array_dados = dados;

   var teste = Array();

   if(idc != null && !idc.checked){
      teste.push(idc.id);
   }else{
      var contador = 0;
      for (var x = 0; x <= array_dados.length; x++) {
         if (typeof array_dados[x] == 'object') {
            if (array_dados[x].checked) {
               teste[x] = array_dados[x].id;
               contador++;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   teste = teste.filter(Boolean);  
   console.log(teste);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Número</th>
      <th>Vencimento</th>
      <th>Parcela</th>
      <th>Valor</th>
      <th>Boleto</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="agrupaPagto" id="10" value="125" name="txtAgrupa" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Art Pneus</td>
      <td><a class="tool_tip" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="2">343</a></td>
      <td>10/10/2017</td>
      <td>2 <b>de</b> 2<span style="color: red"> </span></td>
      <td>R$ 125,00</td>

      <td style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">Em aberto&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_compromissos" onclick="selecionaCompromissos(this)">Pagar</a></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="agrupaPagto" id="11" value="221.00" name="txtAgrupa" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Maria Bonita</td>
      <td><a class="tool_tip" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="teste">532</a></td>
      <td>18/10/2017</td>
      <td>1 <b>de</b> 4<span style="color: red"> </span></td>
      <td>R$ 221,00</td>

      <td style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">Em aberto&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_compromissos" onclick="selecionaCompromissos(this)">Pagar</a></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: excelente a explanação sobre a resposta, é algo do tipo que ensina e também resolve. Valeu.